# Updating Cloud Scheduler Job Triggers Job Run

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-scheduler

Updating an existing job in the GCP Console for Google Cloud Scheduler intermittently results in the job running immediately when the update is saved.

The job type is a GET request to App Engine HTTP. Editing the URL field in the GCP console and saving the job triggers an immediate job run about 50% of the time in my experience of about 10 edits over the last two weeks. The "Frequency" field defining the cron expression has not been edited in my scenario.

I expect the job to only be triggered at the time specified by the "Frequency" field or if the "Run Now" option is invoked. Editing the job resulting in an immediate execution of the job seems like a bug to me. I don't see any information about the expected behavior of a job being edited in the docs.

Note the "Frequency" and "Last run" columns in this screenshot:

[image: Note the frequency and last run columns in this screenshot]

Comment: This seems like feedback for the Cloud Scheduler product, do you have a question?

Comment: @Grayside - Yes the tasks are running when they aren't supposed to as outlined in my post. Do you need more information or clarification on the behavior I am experiencing?